# Included R Script file in SQL query is not executing with PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, rscript

**Store Procedure(AAA_Meeting_XG_boost) sample code**

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
     @language = N'R'
    ,@script = N'source("C:/user/New Product/R code scoring.R");'
    ,@input_data_1 = N''  
    ,@output_data_1_name = N'results' ;
```

Its working fine when it's executing in MS SQL directly but when I hit this query by PHP it's giving the following error:

> **Warning:** sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp64\www\demo\index.php online

**PHP code is:**

```
$Sp2Qquery = "EXEC AAA_Meeting_XG_boost";  
$Sp2Result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $Sp2Qquery);
$Row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($Sp2Result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($Row2);die;
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: So it means you have an error in your query, you can debug it to find out what is the error (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-handle-errors-and-warnings-using-the-sqlsrv-driver?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @VincentDecaux error is not in query its executing and php code is also correct just  R file is not executing

Comment: @Jasbir  Please, place `if ($Sp2Result === false) {echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true); exit;}` after `$Sp2Result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $Sp2Qquery);` and post actual error message. Thanks.

Comment: Yes @Zhorov I tried it but it's  not giving any error except this message: message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]STDERR message(s) from external script: Attaching package: 'plotly' The following object is masked from 'package:ggplot2': last_plot The following object is masked from 'package:graphics': layout Attaching package: 'dplyr' The following objects are masked from 'package:stats': filter, lag The following objects are masked from 'package:base': intersect, setdiff, setequal, union Attaching package: 'xgboost'

Comment: @Jasbir It's a guess, but when you run this script in PHP, this script uses WEB server identity to connect to SQL Server. Maybe this is permissions issue.

Comment: This is also I have checked, Problem is SQL query is returning false due to Include R Script file